# Share a locally stored image to a Facebook wall

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I found some answers for this but I can't put this to work. I'm having some trouble to share a local image to a Facebook wall.

What I want is to upload a local image to a Facebook wall with the share dialog.

I've tried to upload the image with PHP sdk with success, but I was unable to show the share dialog.

With js sdk I'm able to show the share dialog but can't upload a local file without using `<input type='file />'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The share dialog does not offer any possibility to upload an image, you can only share an URL - and of course it has to be an absolute and public one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

The image will be taken from that URL (`og:image` tag).

You can create a custom share dialog, authorize the User with `publish_actions` and use the PHP SDK to upload a picture.

Comment: How can I create a custom share dialog?

Comment: with html and css? ;) - textarea or input field for the message (don´t prefill, that´s not allowed), upload for picture, ...

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help